# Most efficient way to generate Histograms of Oriented Optical Flow (HOOF) in python

Tags: python, performance, computer-vision, histogram, opticalflow

I have a 498-frames-long image sequence for which I calculated optical flow using cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback. Therefore now I have 497 vector maps representing my motion vectors, and these vector are described by magnitude and direction.

What I need to do is to generate a histogram where on the x-axis I have angle ranges in degrees. More specifically, I have 12 bins where the first bin contains all the vectors with direction `0 < angle < 30`, the second one `30 < angle < 60` and so on. On the y-axis, instead, I need to have the sum of the modulus of those vectors contained in each bin.

The problem here is that doing all of this using simple `for` loops and `if` statements takes ages:

```
#magnitude and angle are two np.array of shape (497, 506, 1378)

bins = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
sum = np.zeros_like(bins)

for idx in range(np.array(magnitude).shape[0]): # for each flow map, i.e. for each image pair
    for mag, ang in zip(magnitude[idx].reshape(-1), angle[idx].reshape(-1)): 
        if ang >= 0 and ang <= 30:
            sum[0] += mag
        elif ang > 30 and ang <= 60:
            sum[1] += mag
        elif ang > 60 and ang <= 90:
            sum[2] += mag
        elif ang > 90 and ang <= 120:
            sum[3] += mag
        elif ang > 120 and ang <= 150:
            sum[4] += mag
        elif ang > 150 and ang <= 180:
            sum[5] += mag
        elif ang > 180 and ang <= 210:
            sum[6] += mag
        elif ang > 210 and ang <= 240:
            sum[7] += mag
        elif ang > 240 and ang <= 270:
            sum[8] += mag
        elif ang > 270 and ang <= 300:
            sum[9] += mag
        elif ang > 300 and ang <= 330:
            sum[10] += mag
        elif ang > 330 and ang <= 360:
            sum[11] += mag
```

Which took ~3 hrs to compute. Can somebody suggest a better, more efficient way to perform this calculations?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Edit

Got rid of the conditionals and used Numba to speed it up even further. The following code takes less than 10s to compute:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True) # Set "nopython" mode for best performance, equivalent to @njit
def hoof(magnitude, angle):
    sum = np.zeros(13)

    for idx in range(magnitude.shape[0]): # for each flow map, i.e. for each image pair
        for mag, ang in zip(magnitude[idx].reshape(-1), angle[idx].reshape(-1)): 
            sum[int((ang)//30)] += mag
    
    sum[11] += sum[12]

    return sum[0:12]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conditionals are slow**. You should avoid them as much as possible. Also **Numpy vectorization** and **Numba JIT** help to speed up such a code by a large margin. Here is an untested example:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.jit
def compute(magnitude, angle):
    s = np.zeros(12)
    for idx in range(magnitude.shape[0]):
        for mag, ang in zip(magnitude[idx].reshape(-1), angle[idx].reshape(-1)):
            if ang == 0:
                s[0] += mag
            elif ang > 0 and ang <= 360: # The condition can be removed if always true
                s[(ang-1)//30] += mag
    return s

# Assume both are Numpy array and angle is of type int.
# Note that the first call will be slower unless you precise the types.
compute(magnitude, angle)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The angles are not integers but indeed `s[(ang-1)//30] += mag` is much smarter. Why do you subtract 1 from `mag`? Wouldn't it also work without it?

Comment: If you do subtract 1 and you have really small angles like `ang=0.3` then `(ang-1)//30)= -1`, which is wrong. I guess that's why you were assuming the angles were integers. However, without the `-1` you'll have problems if `ang=360`, since `(360//30)=12` (out of bounds). Anyways, I used a workaround (see edit above) and now the computation takes less than 10s :) Thanks!

Comment: I make a subtraction since 30, 60, etc. are included and not excluded. Indeed, `ang[30//30] == ang[1]`. Yes for `ang=0.3` is does not work as I expected the value to be an integer. You can use `floor` or `ceil` instead with floats (possibly with an addition/substract so that the interval are valid like in the initial code).